# UIBarButtonItem not vertically aligned on custom height UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

[image]

As can be seen in the image above, the UIBarButtonItem is not vertically aligned. The change of alignment happened when I changed the height of the UIToolbar from 44 to 40 (based on the design required).

How can I shift up the UIBarButtonItem so that it sits perfectly in the centre?

Comment: How you changed the height ? It should be 44

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes as I said in the question I have changed the height, but does it **have** to be 44? I am trying to create a bar like in the Find My Friends app and thought UIToolbar would have been most appropriate.

Comment: I'm curious about the fact that you changed the height !!! How did you do that ? AFAIK we can't change the height of toolbars as it's designed to be in 44

Comment: @MidhunMP I did so by simply setting a height constraint on the UIToolbar. Should I use a UIView and UIButton instead, then? I will miss the Flexible Space Items :(

Comment: IMO you should use a UIView and UIButton instead. (What is the need to Flexible item in that context ? You can align the button, wherever you want right ?) For adjusting according to the screen size you can use auto-layout or auto-sizing feature.

Comment: @chrisP Hi Chris, sadly I had to resort to removing the UIBarButtonItem/UIToolbar and just added a view with UIButtons in themselves. This gave me full control over the position of the elements using constraints etc.